# How does rdf refer to rdfs if rdf came earlier?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, rdfs

For example:

```
rdf:Property a rdfs:Class ;
    rdfs:isDefinedBy <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> ;
    rdfs:label "Property" ;
    rdfs:comment "The class of RDF properties." ;
    rdfs:subClassOf rdfs:Resource .
```

From: https://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns

The rdf:Property is referring to several things in the rdfs vocabulary, such as rdfs:Class, despite rdf coming to existence earlier (1996?) than rdfs (1998?).

Comment: The concept of a class existed way before someone decided to call it `rdfs:Class`. Old concepts may easily receive newer concepts in time, after all this could be considered one of the principles of RDF. And `rdf:` and `rdfs:` didn't "come" to existence at a different time, those two namespaces were developed side by side (and are separated for slight semantics reasons).

Answer (score 4):

The distinction between the `rdf:` and `rdfs:` namespaces is not technical, but has more to do with the work of *two separate working groups* at W3C creating the RDF specifications. Mind you, membership in these groups overlapped considerably, as did their timelines.

Having two separate namespaces has been nothing but trouble, we should have gone with just one.

I was there: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-rdf-syntax-19990222/

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts. Could you elaborate on the link?